# can we render only audio in blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

I want to cut a portion of audio file and render in mp3 or aac, but in render tab i can not find any settings for this. i also went through this thread:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?247012-Render-Audio-Only-in-Blender

But i can not see any button called "mixdown" in the scene tab. I am using version 2.74. so is it possible to render only audio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! You have to go to the render panel, then under the render panel and click on the audio icon (next to render and animation).

[image]

Then you can choose different audio outputs and settings (on the left at the bottom of the screen under the tab mixdown).

[image]

And then you push the button mixdown (at the top right).

Answer (score 4):

In Blender version 2.81 you have Menu -> Render -> Render Audio.

Comment: The question was about 2.7x

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth I don't think there's anything wrong with adding the 2.8 answer as well.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot: The answer should give 2.7x solution **first** with optional 2.8. Like: it is/isn't possible and in 2.8...

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth The other answer gives the 2.79 version.