# Render audio button function and use

Tags: rendering

I was wondering what the "Render Audio" button does and how you use it. Is it at all related to the Speaker object?

Comment: I know that if you are using the video sequence editor, you can use the audio render to output only the audio of the sequence. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/can-we-render-only-audio-in-blender/31440#31440 . And I have never noticed the speaker object, so I must check what I can do with that.

Comment: i found an old tutorial from blendernerd https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvH_83_JZCM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render audio button combines all of the audio tracks that have been created in the video sequence editor into one audio file. This is useful if, say you had an animation that had multiple sounds in it but you rendered it as an image sequence and plan to put the output sequence in another project as part of a compilation. Say you forgot that you were going to create all the audio in the compilation. Instead of putting in the numerous audio tracks in again trying to put them in the perfect place **again**, you could render the audio from the first project and put it in the second project parallel to the matching image sequence. Also, it probably works appropriately with the speaker object, but I'm not sure at all. I've never tried. ;)

There's a simple example. I probably could have thought of something more realistic, but I hope that helps!

Comment: Great answer! How do you render a video from the VSE with audio and video? I don't believe raw AVIs work.

Comment: @AnsonSavage You're right. AVI files don't work for that. In the file type option, choose something else. I recommend the H.264 option. Under the encoding tab, go to "audio codec" and choose "MP3." BOOM! Audio. ;)