# Blender VSE - How can I just render the audio to do some editing to it?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I realize that I can use other programs to render out the audio of a video. But I'm trying to keep it all inside Blender for simplicity.

I've just tried deleting the video strip and rendering the audio strip. But that seems to be confusing Blender.

It's also taking about 30 seconds to render one second animation time when I do this.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you setting your export type to something other than video, if there is no video stream? definitely make sure it's not trying to render to an image sequence. Also, disabling the video codec entirely and just rendering an audio stream may help.

Comment: Did you use the *Animation* or the *Audio* (Mixdown) function in the *Render* Panel of your *Properties* View?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/can-we-render-only-audio-in-blender/31440#31440

Comment: Is the audio track synchronized with the video?  Also, why do you want to keep the audio in Blender without the video.  That sounds a lot more complicated than working from the original source material then importing it into Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the video is encoded, you might be able to import video as a sound strip into the VSE.

Goto  Add -> Sound  and when the file selection screen opens, you will have to turn off file filtering.  (So you can select something more than 'sound' files.)

[image]

Then you can select a video file, and it will only import the sound.