# How to render from VSE, and not 3D scene?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

I've an audio strip in video sequence editor and I edited the strip by cutting it from the last, not I want to render it in mp3 format for my animated video.
However when I render it the 3D view camera scene is going to be render and when I deleted the camera it says 'no camera found in the scene'. Please some help me to get the solution.

Comment: Do you have video in the VSE that you would like to see instead of the default cube scene?

Comment: Shady puck, No I didn't add any video clip yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch render source (VSE or Camera)?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39673/how-to-switch-render-source-vse-or-camera)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure, under your *Render Properties* in the *Post Processing* panel you have **Sequencer** checked.

[image: Post Processing Panel]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can render out audio in *.mp3* directly from Blender, but I have discovered a workaround.

You can render out audio by clicking the *Audio* button.

[image]

It's fairly new, so you will need to be using the most recent version of Blender. Also, it will render out audio in a format called *.flac*. I, on my Mac, use an app available in the *App Store* called *SmartConverter*. It's highly rated and very safe. It leaves it in *.mp3*. If you do not have a Mac, I'm sure a software exists for your OS.

Comment: Rendering to audio file is there from at least 2.70. And there isn't any need at all to deal with converting, Audio operation has its own properties with codec selection.

Comment: @MrZak I'm well aware of the codec section, yet the only one that's played for me is AAC, and even with that selected, pure audio still exports as .flac.

Comment: @shady puck, if you render out by clicking the audio button, you can still choose your container (mp3, flac, etc). http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/can-we-render-only-audio-in-blender/31440#31440